# Refactoring a function that uses window.open to use the DOM rather than write()

Tags: javascript, dom, web-standards

I have an application that uses `window.open()` to generate dynamic popups. Unfortunately, I've had trouble creating the content of the new windows using the standard DOM functions (`createElement`, `appendChild`), and I've gone to using `document.write()` to generate the page.

Concretely, how can I go from this:

```
function writePopup()
{
    var popup = window.open("", "popup", "height=400px, width=400px");
    var doc = popup.document;
    doc.write("<html>");
    doc.write("<head>");
    doc.write("<title>Written Popup</title>");
    doc.write("</head>");
    doc.write("<body>");
    doc.write("<p>Testing Write</p>");
    doc.write("</body>");
    doc.write("</html>");
    doc.close();
}
```

To a function that creates the same popup using the DOM?

Edit: I did consider using an absolutely positioned element to simulate a popup, and though it looks better, the users need to be able to print the information being shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a library function such as  http://plugins.jquery.com/project/modaldialog instead of reinventing the wheel?

[EDIT]  OR

```
function writePopup(){
    var popup = window.open("", "_blank", "height=400px, width=400px");
    var doc = popup.document;
    doc.title = 'Written Popup';

    var p = doc.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = 'Testing Write';
    doc.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

Comment: The users need to be able to print the contents of the popup, which rules out anything that uses a faux-popup, like that module.

Comment: you *could* use CSS to hide everything but the (div) popup when printing... a new window is probably easier, but it's still possible without.

Answer (score 2):

Just doing quick tests, I can get doc to append DOM created HTML to my popup like so:

```
var popup = window.open("", "popup", "height=400px, width=400px"); 
var doc = popup.document.documentElement;
var p = document.createElement("p"); 
p.innerHTML = "blah"; 
doc.appendChild(p);
```

My example produces totally invalid HTML I know, but it works (with limited testing obviously).

Answer (score 2):

One dump of .innerHTML should perform better than a zillion lines of document.write();

I would build up the DOM as needed and dump in using

```
doc.innerHTML = newDOM;
```

Still kind of hacky, but better than document.write();

Answer (score 2):

> I've gone to using document.write() to generate the page.

I think you will probably have to use at least some document.write(), to put a skeleton page in place before you can interact with the DOM:

```
doc.write('<!DOCTYPE ...><html><head></head><body></body></html>');
doc.close();
doc.body.appendChild(...);
```

Before write() has been called, a new window's document is in an indeterminate state, there is no document yet to interact with. Firefox at least puts a temporary skeleton document in until you first call document.write(), but I can't see that this is actually documented anywhere so it's probably best not relied upon.

> var popup = window.open("", "popup", "height=400px, width=400px");

No ‘px’ unit needed in window.open.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to have another page that generates the dynamic content, and pop it open, passing arguments that identify the content you want generated, instead of trying to write to a new window?

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like

```
function writePopup(){
  var htmlString=[
    "<html>",
    "<head>",
    "<title>Written popup</title>",
    "</head><body>",
    "<p>Testing write</p>",
    "</body></html>"
  ].join("\n");
  window.open("data:text/html,"+encodeURIComponent(htmlString), "_blank", "height=400px, width=400px");
}
```