# "the remote procedure call failed" - IE only

Tags: javascript, .net, internet-explorer

I'm trying to open a new window with javascript and fill it with the html from the current window. Sort of like a print preview in a new window and with a new css.

```
function prnt() {
        var pr = window.open("", "", "width=1020,height=750");
        pr.document.open();
        pr.document.write('<html><head><title>Test</title>');
        pr.document.write('<link href=print.css rel=Stylesheet></head><body>');
        pr.document.write(document.body.innerHTML);
        pr.document.write('</body></html>');
        pr.document.close();
        pr.focus();}
```

I'm calling this function from here:

```
<a id="print" href="#" runat="server" onclick="javascript:prnt();">PRINT</a>
```

IE gives me the error **the remote procedure call failed** and it seems to be pointing to this line:
*pr.document.close();*

Everything works fine in FF though. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I'm running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
SP1

**EDIT2**
If I remove *pr.document.close();* the page works perfect in IE and *done* is displayed in the status bar.
However, now FF won't work properly. The page never actually stops loading. I guess it's waiting for the *pr.document.close();* command?

Comment: What does `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(...)` do?

Comment: I've updated it without .NET specific tags. I think the problem is with the javascript though.

Comment: But do you get the same error when you throw out that function call in your actual page? *Never* trust IE's line number in error messages.

Comment: Yes, I get the same error. I've edited my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as beautiful as it is an easy solution, but it seem to be working.
I replaced this line of code:

```
pr.document.close();
```

with this line:

```
if (navigator.appName != "Microsoft Internet Explorer") pr.document.close();
```

Comment: Of course this is an ugly hack, but it does not solve your *actual* problem: e.g., I also used `document.write` and `document.close` to populate a new window, but I never got this error in IE.

Answer (score 3):

Use the DOM...document.write is [evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

On how to do it check [here](http://javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml):

Comment: In essence, you're right, but not when writing to a new window: "I think you will probably have to use at least some document.write(), to put a skeleton page in place before you can interact with the DOM" ([read on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265398/refactoring-a-function-that-uses-window-open-to-use-the-dom-rather-than-write/541456#541456)).

Comment: If you can supply a working javascript wich uses the DOM I'll mark this as the best answer =)